# how can i vertically align an element with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i know that this question has been asked many time but none of the solution is working for me. i simply want to align one label inside one div that is associated with a twitter-bootstrap class. but it is not being aligned. I have tried horizontal alignment with this and it was working fine. without bootstrap it was working fine but with bootstrap it stopped working.
any idea how it will work ?

Comment: here is the link to my Fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/akki166786/s7Wb4/` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

with the use of

```
display:table;
```

and

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

This way the label will always be centered, even if you resize the box

http://jsfiddle.net/s7Wb4/2/

Comment: thanks for exact answer but with a slight change it is not working again here is my new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/akki166786/jBCAG/

Comment: @akshay This is because bootstrap overwrites your styles, be sure to overwrite them. I did it with !important which is not nice, but it work's http://jsfiddle.net/jBCAG/1/

Answer (score 1):

Address the label instead

```
.center{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
}
.center label {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

forked jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s5dJH/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` to your `label` and set it the same height as your `div`. This will align it perfectly.

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RX2Ld/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/s7Wb4/9/

```
.center{
width : 100px;
height : 100px;
display : table-cell;
float:none !important;
vertical-align : middle;
border : 1px solid red;
}
```